# Doubts about passing by reference

Tags: c++, function, reference

i'm studying C++ and, in particular,i have stopped on references. I apologize if my question will be trivial to most of you,but i would like to understand the output of this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

myStruct copyMyStruct(myStruct& source)
{
    myStruct dest;
    dest.a=source.a;
    dest.b=source.b;
    return dest;
}

myStruct otherCopyMyStruct(myStruct& source)
{
    myStruct dest;
    dest=source;
    return dest;
}

myStruct& GetRef(myStruct& source)
{
    return source;
}

void printMyStruct(string name,const myStruct& str)
{
    cout<<name<<".a:"<<str.a<<endl;
    cout<<name<<".b:"<<str.b<<endl;
}

myStruct one,two,three,four;
myStruct& five=one;

void printStructs()
{
    printMyStruct("one",one);
    printMyStruct("two",two);
    printMyStruct("three",three);
    printMyStruct("four",four);
    printMyStruct("five",five);
}

int main()
{
    one.a=100;
    one.b=200;

    two=copyMyStruct(one);
    three=otherCopyMyStruct(one);
    four=GetRef(one);


    printStructs();

    cout<<endl<<"NOW MODIFYING one"<<endl;

    one.a=12345;
    one.b=67890;

    printStructs();

    cout<<endl<<"NOW MODIFYING two"<<endl;

    two.a=2222;
    two.b=2222;

    printStructs();

    cout<<endl<<"NOW MODIFYING three"<<endl;

    three.a=3333;
    three.b=3333;

    printStructs();

    cout<<endl<<"NOW MODIFYING four"<<endl;

    four.a=4444;
    four.b=4444;

    printStructs();


    cout<<endl<<"NOW MODIFYING five"<<endl;

    five.a=5555;
    five.b=5555;

    printStructs();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
one.a:100
one.b:200
two.a:100
two.b:200
three.a:100
three.b:200
four.a:100
four.b:200
five.a:100
five.b:200

NOW MODIFYING one
one.a:12345
one.b:67890
two.a:100
two.b:200
three.a:100
three.b:200
four.a:100
four.b:200
five.a:12345
five.b:67890

NOW MODIFYING two
one.a:12345
one.b:67890
two.a:2222
two.b:2222
three.a:100
three.b:200
four.a:100
four.b:200
five.a:12345
five.b:67890

NOW MODIFYING three
one.a:12345
one.b:67890
two.a:2222
two.b:2222
three.a:3333
three.b:3333
four.a:100
four.b:200
five.a:12345
five.b:67890

NOW MODIFYING four
one.a:12345
one.b:67890
two.a:2222
two.b:2222
three.a:3333
three.b:3333
four.a:4444
four.b:4444
five.a:12345
five.b:67890

NOW MODIFYING five
one.a:5555
one.b:5555
two.a:2222
two.b:2222
three.a:3333
three.b:3333
four.a:4444
four.b:4444
five.a:5555
five.b:5555
```

My question: why don't the changes on "two","three" and "four" produce a change on "one"?

I can guess what happens to "two" and "three": probably a member by member copy to a newly created variable, but i don't understand why the change on "four" isn't reflected on "one" (and "five"): after all i return a reference from the GetRef function ....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: GetRef returns the same-same, but what happens when you assign to `four`? It's not a ref...

Answer (score 8):

The variable `four` is an object, not a reference.

When you assign to it from a reference, `four=GetRef(one);`, `four` doesn't turn into a reference. The assignment copies whatever is referred to by the reference (in this case, that referand is `one`). After that, the objects are unrelated. So `four = GetRef(one);` has the same effect as `four = one;`.

`myStruct &five = one;`, on the other hand, declares `five` as a reference (not an object), and "binds" the object `one` to the reference. So the name `five` and the name `one` refer to the same object, meaning that of course changes made using either name can be seen using the other name.

By the way, there's no need[*] for `typedef struct myStruct myStruct;` in C++. In C++, a class type can just be referred to by name, and structs *are* classes.

[*] except for a somewhat weird corner case where you have a function with the same name as a class, whose parameters are compatible with the parameters of some constructor of that class. Then you might think the expression `Foo(x,y)` would be ambiguous between the function `Foo` and the constructor call on `Foo`. But no - in the absence of a typedef, C of course chooses the function, and so for compatibility with C, C++ does the same thing. Most people don't find this case compelling enough to write the typedefs in C++.

Comment: More detailed-ly, one would say that `four=GetRef(one)` calls the assignment operator `myStruct::operator =(myStruct &copyfromthis)`. If you don't define an assignment operator, the compiler invents one which by default does a member-by-member copy.

Comment: Yes. In this case, assignment copies the object as I said above, but for classes that overload `operator=`, assignment does whatever that overload defines it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because copymystruct returns 'by value'. It involves creating a seperate temporary object which is returned by value and assigned to the result which is a separate object.